# Error: unexpected symbol in RScript - No further information provided about the line or syntax generating error

Tags: r, postgresql, syntax-error

I have read the many posts related to R Syntax errors, but everyone points to the error message and using it to figure out where the error occurs. My situation is different in that the error is generic. See below:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "RScript correlation_presalesfinal3.R"

RStudio executes it fine.

It is an incredibly simple script, and I am wondering if it has to do with how I am constructing my Postgres syntax. Does R require line break symbols between the statements (select, from, group by etc)?

That is the only thing I can thing of. I am trying to compare a separate R-generated correlation to one generated by PostgreSQL directly. This particular piece is the call to PostgreSQL to calculate correlation directly.

I appreciate your help!

Here is the code:

```
#Written by Laura for Standard Imp

#Install if necessary (definitely on the first run)
install.packages("RColorBrewer")
install.packages("gplots")
install.packages("RSclient")
install.packages("RPostgreSQL")

#libraries in use
  library(RColorBrewer)
  library(gplots)
  library(RSclient)
  library(RPostgreSQL)

# Establish connection to PostgreSQL using RPostgreSQL
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

# Full version of connection setting
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="db",host="ip",port=5432,user="user",password="pwd")
# -----------------------------^--------^-------------------^----  -------^
myLHSRHSFinalTable <- dbGetQuery(con,"select l1.a_lhsdescription as LHS, l2.a_rhsdescription as RHS, l7.a_scenariodescription as Scenario, corr(l3.driver_metric, l4.driver_metric) as Amount from schema_name.table_name l3 join schema_name.table_name l4 on L3.Time_ID = l4.Time_ID join schema_name.opera_00004_dim_lhs l1 on l3.LHS_ID = l1.member_id join schema_name.opera_00004_dim_rhs l2 on l4.RHS_ID = l2.member_id join schema_name.opera_00004_dim_scenario l7 on l3.scenario_id = l7.member_id join schema_name.opera_00004_dim_time l8 on l3.time_id = l8.member_id where l7.a_scenariodescription = 'Actual' 
group by l1.a_lhsdescription , l2.a_rhsdescription,  l7.a_scenariodescription ")

myLHSRHSFinalTable

write.csv(myLHSRHSFinalTable, file = "data_load_stats_final.csv")

# Close PostgreSQL connection 
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Comment: Looks like you have some non-standard quotes in this file. For example at `“db"` -- you have a fancy unicode opening quote but a standard ascii closing quote. Does that exist in the actual file you are running? The problem seems like your file encoding.

Comment: Highlighted as an edit. This generally implies that useR is not using an appropriate IDE for development.

Comment: Thanks, MrFlick. I just noticed the non-standard quotes - I am not doing anything special. I wonder though it is was when I cut/paste into my post vs. my actual R. script? I created the original file in R studio and am trying to execute it via command prompt on the server. Do you know if there is any notation which I can use to generate better logging of the error instead of such a generate message?

Comment: Still looking for help on this error. I have stripped my script down to just the lines of code (no comments) even. I can run it line by line directly in RScript command window without error. I can run it as a full script in RStudio with no error. It is only when I tried to execute the script fully (instead of line by line) that I get the error. Why would that be the case?

Comment: Hi, I ran into the same issue. Could you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the problem possibly lacks enough detail for people to answer, but in my situation I ran into this same error message because I was executing `Rscript` from within the R shell. The documentation in R isn't always clear, as neither is the help, for indicating to the user where the commands are to be executed.

If you're working from the 'terminal' you use `Rscript` to run an R script, whereas if you're working from within the 'R shell' you use `source()` to run an R script.

As I'm still a newbie, I'm sure this answer is too much of an oversimplification, but it works to solve the basic error I was getting.

My script file called output.R can be executed from the 'terminal' command line prompt ("$") within my Linux system by the command:

```
$Rscript output.R
```

Or alternatively from within R, by first running the R shell, then executing the command at the R prompt (">")

```
$R

>source("output.R")
```